# Symbol not found: _PyClass_Type

Tags: python, macos, fastparquet

I'm to run some tests from [fastparquet](https://github.com/dask/fastparquet) using pyCharm on macOS Sierra (10.12.6) but keep failing on:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/dhaviv/Documents/GitHub/fastparquet/fastparquet/speedups.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyClass_Type
```

I've installed boost-python3 but that didn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import dlib ImportError Symbol not found: \_PyClass\_Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45923202/import-dlib-importerror-symbol-not-found-pyclass-type)

Comment: check the dlib version, otherwise install it for python3: `pip3 install dlib`